# Laravel custom logging

Tags: php, laravel, logging, monolog

I am using laravel monolog to separate INFO, WARNING, and ERROR logs

link : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/advance-logging-with-laravel-and-monolog

I have copied and it is working.

My only problem is about the ERROR logging,

when we check out daily error logs it looks good and line breaks every number
e.g.

```
Stack trace:
#0 'Error exception with message of undefined'
#1 .../location line (44)
```

but the custom logging does not line break with these numbers. Is this normal or i have did something wrong in my configuration?

i have tried to use a formatter and doesnt work still

```
$logFormat = "%datetime% [%level_name%] (%channel%): %message% %context% %extra%\n";
    $formatter = new LineFormatter($logFormat);
    $errorStreamHandler->setFormatter($formatter);
    $infoStreamHandler->setFormatter($formatter);
```

the error still looks like shown below without any line breaks

```
Stack trace: #0 'Error exception with message of undefined'    #1 .../location line (44)
```

Is there a workaround to have the line break after every number line

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check the LineFormatter documentation (https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Formatter/LineFormatter.php) and set allowInlineLineBreaks to true when creating a new formatter, like so:

```
$formatter = new LineFormatter($logFormat, null, true);
```